# how use more than one routings file in django-channels?

Tags: python, django, channel

I am making a project in which i use channels in two different apps.but how can i make two  different routings files for each app

```
import os
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter,URLRouter
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from channels.http import AsgiHandler
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from consultation import routings as consultation_routings
from chat import routings as chat_routings


os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'sqh.settings._base')

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "http":AsgiHandler(),
    "websocket":AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            consultation_routings.websocket_urlpatterns,
            chat_routings.websocket_urlpatterns,
        )
    )
})
```

when i add a second routings file address to URLRouter in asgi.py it raises following error :

```
    URLRouter(
TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Comment: `URLRouter(consultation_routings.websocket_urlpatterns+chat_routings.websocket_urlpatterns)`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks